# Change InCellDropdown for Range with different validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Sheet with multiple cells with different data validations. With a ToggleButton I want to turn the dropdown lists on or off. I came up with the following code:

```
Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("activeFields")
rng.Validation.InCellDropdown = False

Else

Set rng = Range("activeFields")
rng.Validation.InCellDropdown = True

End If
End Sub
```

The Range "activeFields" is a named range off all the cells with data validation. The code only works, if I select fields that have the same data validation. Is there a way to make it work for all cells without selecting them separately? There are a lot of them.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
Sub kfhsdf()
    Dim r As Range, rr
    Set r = Range("mylist")

    MsgBox Range("mylist").Address(0, 0)
    For Each rr In r
        rr.Validation.InCellDropdown = False
    Next rr
End Sub
```

[image]

Where `Range("mylist")` is dis-joint.